# Local Storage not saving everything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I'm trying to use the local storage to save a specific state in redux so that the client would not have to make the axios calls every time to fill up the database. However, only 71% of the given database seems to be saving in the local storage every time, and I wasn't sure why this was happening.

This is my local storage code (using the one in Dan's tutorial).

```
export const loadState = () => {
    try {
        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
        if(serializedState === null){
            return undefined
        }
        return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (err){
        return undefined;
    }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
    try {
        const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    } catch(err){
        ///
    }
};
```

Setting up the store

```
const persistedState = loadState();
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers, persistedState);

store.subscribe(()=>{
    saveState({
        pokemons: store.getState().pokemons
    });
});
```

The component is supposed to look for the current pokemon array's length to determine whether it needs to make more axios calls.

```
componentDidMount(){
    let promises = [];
    for(var i = this.props.pokemons.length; i < 10; i++){
        promises.push(this.props.fetchPokemons(i));
    }
    axios.all(promises).then(()=>{
        this.props.mapPokemons(this.props.pokemons);
        this.setState({
            loading: false
        })
    })
}
```

Every time the page is refreshed, the this.props.pokemons only seems to be holding 71% of the data. Even when I clear the local storage and try to fill up the redux state again, only 71% of the data is there when I refresh the page.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Size you attempt to store?

Comment: How big is the data? Local storage has limits. But I'd expect you to get a storage exception if you were exceeding them.

Comment: AND the specific device/browser?  Is this mobile ?

Comment: I'm saving 30 pokemon data from the Pokeapi. I don't think it should be more than 5 MB, but I'm not entirely sure. The browser I'm using is google chrome on the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are trying to store more data than the maximum memory available for local storage, which is, for Google Chrome (for example), [5MB](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage).

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the data that you want to put in the sotrage ? Because if the size is bigger than 5MB, only 5MB will be stored